# Conditional Rendering of Arrays in React: For vs Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and building a calendar application. While playing around with state to try understand it better, I noticed that my 'remove booking' function required a state update for it to work, while my 'add booking' function worked perfectly without state.

Remove bookings: requires state to work

```
const [timeslots, setTimeslots] = useState(slots);
    

    const removeBookings = (bookingid) => {
        
        let newSlots = [...timeslots];
        delete newSlots[bookingid].bookedWith;
        setTimeslots(newSlots);
    }
```

Add bookings: does not require state to work

```
   const addBookings = (slotid, tutorName) => {
        timeslots[slotid].bookedWith = tutorName;
      }
```

I think that this is because of how my timeslot components are rendered. Each slot is rendered from an item of an array through .map(), as most tutorials online suggest is the best way to render components from an array.

```
timeslots.map(slot => {
                
                if (!slot.bookedWith) {
                return <EmptyTimeslot [...props / logic] />
                } else {
                    return <BookedTimeslot [...props / logic]/> 
                }
                
                })
```

So, with each EmptyTimeslot, the data for a BookedTimeslot is available as well. That's why state is not required for my add bookings function (emptyTimeslot -> bookedTimeslot). However, removing a booking (bookedTimeslot -> emptyTimeslot) requires a rerender of the slots, since the code cannot 'flow upwards'.

There are a lot of slots that have to be rendered each time. My question is therefore, instead of mapping each slot (with both  and  information present in each slot), would it be more efficient to use a for loop to only render the relevant slot, rather than the information for both slots? This I assume would require state to be used for both the add booking and remove booking function. Like this:

```
     for (let i=0;i<timeslots.length;i++) {
             if (!timeslot[i].bookedWith) {
                  return <EmptyTimeslot />
    } else {
                  return <BookedTimeslot />
}
    }
```

Hope that makes sense. Thank you for any help.

Comment: you can do this ```  const [state, setState] = useState({booking: []}) const onDeleteBooking = (id) => {setState({...state, bookin: state.booking.filter(function(x) {return x.id !== id})})}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addBooking` function is *bad*. Even if it seems to "work", you should not be mutating your state values. You should be using a state setter function to update them, which is what you are doing in `removeBookings`.

> My question is therefore, instead of mapping each slot (with both and information present in each slot), would it be more efficient to use a for loop to only render the relevant slot, rather than the information for both slots?

Your `map` approach is not rendering both. For each slot, it uses an `if` statement to return one component or the other depending on whether the slot is booked. I'm not sure how the `for` loop you're proposing would even work here. It would just `return` before the first iteration completed.

> This I assume would require state to be used for both the add booking and remove booking function.

You *should* be using `setTimeslots` for *all* timeslot state updates and you should *not* be mutating your state values. That is true no matter how you render them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you elaborate on why my add booking function 'works' without state? I get that mutating state directly can mess things up, but not clear why a <BookedTimeslot /> is rendered even without the setTimeslots function.

Comment: @JoeJohnson To be honest, I'm not sure why it works and I'm not sure if there is enough information in your question to deduce why it does. It may be that there's something you haven't shown us that's causing the re-render and that the `addBookings` function is not the cause of it. I would advise trying to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in codesandbox or some place similar. If you can do that, I could try to figure out why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: yes - you were right. I had another function rendering a dropdown menu that was causing the rerender of all the slots. Thanks so much.